# Downloading transactions into QuickBooks

Tags: java, quickbooks, quickbooks-online, intuit-partner-platform

I'm developing an Java web application in which users have an opportunity to see and download their transactions. I would like to have a feature to download transaction into QuickBooks. I know that I can import transactions into .OFX format, but I'm wondering if it is possible to download transactions into QuickBooks Online via QuickBooks API? Any suggestions? Examples are appreciated.

I have took a look on the API and I have seen customers, invoices, payment and other things that can be done using API, but I haven't seen nothing about transactions.

And one more question. In which way do the QuickBooks adds financial institution and how is it possible to be QuickBooks supported financial institution? Thank you.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

From your java app, you can read all transactions from the .ofx file, parse the data to construct payload for required QB API( transaction entities like - Invoice, SalesReceipt, Payments etc) and finally call those APIs to insert data into QB account.

To generate OAuth tokens which you'll be using while calling APIs, you can refer the following links.

To start development using QB API, you need to create an IA apps in Intuit's appcenter.
https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0025_quickbooksapi/0010_getting_started/0010_signup

From the above link you will get - apptoken, consumer key and consumer Secret. You can use the above 3 keys in IPPOAuthPlayground(PFB link) to get the access token and access secret corresponding to your QB Online account. 
https://appcenter.intuit.com/Playground/OAuth

To test endpoints, you can refer APIExplorer tool. 
https://developer.intuit.com/apiexplorer?apiname=V3QBO

Using the above tokens, you can call any REST endpoints against your QB Online account.

If you want to download transactions directly from FIs, then you might want to have a look at CAD APIs.

https://developer.intuit.com/docs/0020_customeraccountdata

Thanks

Comment: Thanks a lot for the answer. Don't you know what is required to become a financial institution for QuickBooks? Can I request somehow to implement this API in my application?

Comment: I'm nost sure what do you mean be "what is required to become a financial institution for QuickBooks". If you want to use any external FIs (around 19K are supported by CAD APIs) then you can start using CAD APIs. In the doc, you'll find all required details of it.

Comment: I mean, that how I can register a financial company as a FI (that is not currently supported)? Is it possible to request that?

Comment: You can raise a support ticket mentioning the FI details from this link - https://developer.intuit.com/Support/Incidents
Thanks